# Are these indexes mutually exclusive?

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL 2008 database that I'm trying to tune and I've used some samples I've found for generating recommended indexes from the SQL data management views.

In several cases, I see multiple indexes recommended and these have identical definitions up until the INCLUDE part, at which point they have some different columns along for the ride.

I know that I should not just create every index that a script from the internet suggests, but beyond that, if I did create all of these, will the engine use each of these indexes, as appropriate, or will two of them go unused?

```
CREATE INDEX [IX_FactBilling_FiscalPeriodKey1]
  ON [ClearViewDev].[Performance].[FactBilling] ([fiscalperiodkey])
  include ([TotalReceived], [ExchangeRateTimeKey], [MatterKey], [BillingTypeKey]
, [CurrencyKey], [PersonKey], [CompanyKey], [OfficeKey], [PracticeGroupKey],
[ProfitCenterKey], [PersonnelTypeKey], [RankKey])

CREATE INDEX [IX_FactBilling_FiscalPeriodKey2]
  ON [ClearViewDev].[Performance].[FactBilling] ([fiscalperiodkey])
  include ([TotalBilled], [ExchangeRateTimeKey], [MatterKey], [BillingTypeKey],
[CurrencyKey], [PersonKey], [CompanyKey], [OfficeKey], [PracticeGroupKey],
[ProfitCenterKey], [PersonnelTypeKey], [RankKey])

CREATE INDEX [IX_FactBilling_FiscalPeriodKey3]
  ON [ClearViewDev].[Performance].[FactBilling] ([fiscalperiodkey])
  include ([TotalBilled], [TotalReceived], [MatterKey], [BillingTypeKey],
[TransactionDateKey], [BusinessProcessInstanceDateKey], [PersonKey],
[CompanyKey], [OfficeKey], [PracticeGroupKey], [ProfitCenterKey],
[PersonnelTypeKey], [RankKey], [BillableHoursBilled], [BillableValueBilled],
[StandardValueBilled], [HoursBilled])
```

Comment: What is your clustered index key on `FactBilling`?

Comment: No clustered key.  "ID" is the primary key.

Comment: So, `ID` is a non-clustered primary key ?

Comment: Yes, Bogdan.  That's the unambiguous (better) way to say it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To strictly answer the question:

1. TotalReceived, ExchangeRateTimeKey, MatterKey, BillingTypeKey, CurrencyKey, PersonKey, CompanyKey, OfficeKey, PracticeGroupKey, ProfitCenterKey, PersonnelTypeKey, RankKey
2. TotalBilled, ExchangeRateTimeKey, MatterKey, BillingTypeKey, CurrencyKey, PersonKey, CompanyKey, OfficeKey, PracticeGroupKey, ProfitCenterKey, PersonnelTypeKey, RankKey
3. TotalBilled, TotalReceived, MatterKey, BillingTypeKey, TransactionDateKey, BusinessProcessInstanceDateKey, PersonKey, CompanyKey, OfficeKey, PracticeGroupKey, ProfitCenterKey, PersonnelTypeKey, RankKey, BillableHoursBilled, BillableValueBilled, StandardValueBilled, HoursBilled

Index 1 and 2 are same except for the first field (`TotalReceived` vs `TotalBilled`). Index 3 is different from 1 and 2. In theory a query that requires `TotalBilled` is not covered by index 2 and a query that requires `TotalReceive` is not covered by index 1. But is all theoretical.

Nobody in a right mind would consider adding these 3 indices. They're too wide. What the optimizer is hinting to you is that it would really, really like the `FiscalPeriodKey` to be the leftmost key in the clustered index. In time series the best choice for clustered keys is the time key, because time series are most often queried for time ranges. Alas, with DW fact tables the time is only *one* of the query dimensions, often the other dimensions (eg. geography, organizational unit, product family) are also used for queries. And you can only pick *one* as hte clustered key. Pushing the covering index approach to the limit to cover all these cases results in huge data size bloat and poor write performance. Ultimately, you are faced with the realization that you're using the wrong tool for the job.

I would recommend you investigate upgrading to [columnstores](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx). All these problems will dissapear as columnar storage uses a completely different approach and the queries benefit from [segment elimination](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/5651.understanding-segment-elimination.aspx). Of course, this 
requires SQL Server 2012 at least, and recommended SQL Server 2014 for [updatable columnstores](http://rusanu.com/2013/06/11/sql-server-clustered-columnstore-indexes-at-teched-2013/).

A more palatable solution is to bite the bullet and deploy an SSAS cube. MOLAP thrives with these kind of problems where the relational server simply has no answer (at least no prior to columnstores).

> No clustered key. "ID" is the primary key

I will assume you mean 'ID is an identity used as the primary key and by default the clustered key'. If you really mean that you have a heap with a non-clustered primary key `ID` then.. you deserve the problems you got and much worse.

A common workaround for the issue you're facing (well known in the industry under the moniker of ['index tipping point'](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/category/the-tipping-point/)) is to leverage the correlation between ID and time of insert. A lookaside table which stores min and max IDs for specific time ranges is used to restrict the clustered index scan. See [Disposable Indexes](http://sqlfool.com/2010/12/disposable-indexes/) for a specific example. But the correlation exists only for one dimension (time), not for other DW dimenssions so you're back to the same issues as choosing a clustered index time key. Again, SSAS cubes or columnstores are more appropriate for the task.

Comment: "If you really mean that you have a heap with a non-clustered primary key ID then.. you deserve the problems you got and much worse."  LOL.  Thank you, Remus, for the great detail, the suggestions, and the "tough love".